# ESP32 Standalone: Timed out waiting for packet header

Tags: upload, esp32, uart, arduino-ide, arduino-esp32

I am currently running an ESP32 standalone on a board I created myself. Now I have the problem that I get the following error when uploading my program from the Arduino IDE:

```
Sketch uses 718674 bytes (54%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.
Global variables use 39428 bytes (12%) of dynamic memory, leaving 288252 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.
esptool.py v3.0-dev
Serial port COM4
Connecting....
Chip is ESP32-D0WD (revision 1)
Features: WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
Crystal is 40MHz
MAC: ec:62:60:cc:1e:14
Uploading stub...
Running stub...
Stub running...
Configuring flash size...
Warning: Could not auto-detect Flash size (FlashID=0x0, SizeID=0x0), defaulting to 4MB
Compressed 8192 bytes to 47...
Writing at 0x0000e000... (100 %)
Wrote 8192 bytes (47 compressed) at 0x0000e000 in 0.0 seconds (effective 4096.0 kbit/s)...

A fatal error occurred: Timed out waiting for packet header
Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 2
```

If I connect the microcontroller to the supply voltage, I get the following information in the serial monitor:

```
rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0x1f (SPI_FAST_FLASH_BOOT)
configsip: 0, SPIWP:0xee
clk_drv:0x00,q_drv:0x00,d_drv:0x00,cs0_drv:0x00,hd_drv:0x00,wp_drv:0x00
mode:DIO, clock div:2
load:0x3fffeba4,len:4
load:0x4009f000,len:3248
entry 0x4009f574
```

When setting the microcontroller to boot mode, I get the following message in the serial monitor:

```
rst:0x10 (RTCWDT_RTC_RESET),boot:0xf (UART_BOOT(UART0))
```

With an old version of the board, when I put it into boot mode, I also got the message "Waiting for download" in the serial monitor. This does not appear with the current version of the board

[Wiring of the ESP32](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAXdn.png)

The attached picture shows the wiring of the ESP32 standalone. To set the boot mode I use jumpers to pull the pins to the corresponding potentials.The programming takes place via UART.Furthermore, an acceleration sensor (BMI) and some singals for the evaluation of measuring bridges (DMS) are connected to the ESP32.

In the Arduino IDE I have selected as board the FireBeetle-ESP32. This also worked for the old version of the board.

The program also runs on an ESP32 development board so I don't suspect an error in the program

I am grateful for ideas by which the problem could be caused. Thank you all!

Comment: What I can add: I have measured the potentials which are applied by the jumpers and the supply voltage of the ESP32. These are correct